# Creating a string from a list of names and write it in a txt file using PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis

I would like to write the names of all the layers (that are displayed each time) in a txt file.
I am creating a list with all the names and then I combine the names in a string by accessing the list.
I have written the following script that is working just fine for 2 layers but I would like to make it flexible so that it will work for unknown number of layers.
I would like to create a loop and combine the layer names from the list in a string regardless how  many layers there are in the list.

```
#Write the names of the layers in a txt file
names = [layer.name() for layer in QgsProject.instance().mapLayers().values()]
a = names[0]+', '+names[1]

textFilePath = 'P:/Test.txt'
f = open( textFilePath, 'wt')
f.write(a)
f.close()
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just convert

```
a = names[0]+', '+names[1]
```

to

```
a = ', '.join(names)
```